Work with vertex buffer with several streams in compute shader

Hello. I'm trying work in compute shader with vertext buffer containing many streams
Position in first stream
Tangent and Color in second
UV coords in third
How can I pass this data into compute shader and reseive it there?
P.S: If I put all data into one stream everything works fine.
Here is Unity C# code for one stream:
var mesh = meshFilter.mesh;
var vertexBuffer = meshFilter.graphicsBuffer;
m_paintMeshShader.SetBuffer(m_paintKernelHandle, Vertices, vertexBuffer);
m_paintMeshShader.SetInt(VertexCount, mesh.vertexCount);
m_paintMeshShader.SetInt(TargetVertexOffset, mesh.GetVertexAttributeOffset(VertexAttribute.Position));
m_paintMeshShader.SetInt(TargetColorOffset, mesh.GetVertexAttributeOffset(VertexAttribute.Color));
m_paintMeshShader.SetInt(TangentOffset, mesh.GetVertexAttributeOffset(VertexAttribute.Tangent));
m_paintMeshShader.SetInt(TargetMaxOffset, vertexBuffer.stride);
m_paintMeshShader.Dispatch(m_paintKernelHandle, (mesh.vertexCount + 31) / 31, 1, 1);

Here is hlsl compute shader code for one stream:
int vertexCount;
int targetVertexOffset;
int targetColorOffset;
int tangentOffset;
int targetMaxOffset;
RWByteAddressBuffer vertices;

[numthreads(32, 1, 1)]
void Paint(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    uint index = id.x;
    if (index >= asuint(vertexCount))
        return;

    int targetIndex = index * targetMaxOffset;
    float2 positionDefaultPacked = asfloat(vertices.Load2(targetIndex + targetVertexOffset)); 
    uint colorDefalutPacked = asuint(vertices.Load(targetIndex + targetColorOffset)));
    uint2 tangentDefalutPacked = asuint(vertices.Load2(targetIndex + tangentOffset)));
//...do some work
}

